# Netlogo if statement with myself and other

Tags: netlogo

I'm fairly new to Netlogo and struggling with how to set up a somewhat complicated if statement. The statement is for turtles and the condition is that other turtles live in the same region and have a house.

I've tried the iterations of the following, but have not yet been successful:

```
if (one-of other turtles with [region = [region] of myself and house? = True]) []

if (other turtles with [region = [region] of myself and house? = True]) []
```

Thank you for any insights!

Answer (score 2):

If you need to insert code in a question, check out the "Code Sample" button in the toolbar. You can highlight your code and click the button- super handy.

Your second try is extremely close. The quick fix is to add the `any?` primitive in order to tell Netlogo that you want to evaluate the agentset "other turtles" in this case. As it was, you weren't actually evaluating anything with `if`- kind of like saying "If the turtles in my region who have a house," as opposed to "If there are any turtles in my region who have a house."

```
to check-region
  ask one-of turtles [
    if any? other turtles with [ region = [region] of myself and house? = true ] [
      set color white
    ]
  ]
end
```

If you need to evaluate more specific numbers, you can use something like `count` to set a threshold - for example:

```
to check-region-count
  ask one-of turtles [
    if count other turtles with [ region = [region] of myself and house? = true ] > 3 [
      set color white
    ]
  ]
end
```